# Gtk 3.10 ignores gtk_box_set_child_packing

Tags: haskell, gtk

As written in the title, I have trouble specifying child packing properties inside an hbox/vbox with Gtk 3.10 (on Ubuntu 14.04), where the same code works with Gtk 3.20 (on Archlinux). The minimal code to reproduce the bug is the following (pardon my Haskell) :

```
import Graphics.Widget -- my graphics library, which uses the FFI to import Gtk functions

main = runApplication $ do
  a <- (subwidget.text) "aaa"; b <- (subwidget.text) "bbb"
  setDynamic a (packing.expands) Fitting
  c <- box2 Horizontal a b
  window "Main window" c <| do visible =- True
```

This code compiles and runs with the two Gtk versions, but the Gtk 3.10 version seems to ignore the second line and shows both child widgets expanding equally into the hbox. The Gtk 3.20 version does what is expected and shows the first widget packed to the left and the second one taking the remaining space. Other than that, no error is being reported from either Gtk version.

Can you help me understand what changed ? I've read the docs, and I haven't found a reasonable explanation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, my Haskell code was calling gtk_hbox_new, which is clearly stated to be deprecated in the docs. I switched to gtk_box_new and now the child widgets are correctly laid out with both Gtk versions.